# How to get access to objects that have been deleted in Model in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am developing a parking management system in Django that records the 'Vehicle' object according to its time of entry, and calculates the value as it leaves, but I need to develop a reporting system that returns how many cars entered and how much total value of the day.

How can I get access to vehicles that have left, because on my system, after the checkout, the object is deleted in the database to report in the report.

```
# models.py 
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    vehicle_plate = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False)
    entry_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle_plate


class Price(models.Model):
    morning = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,
                              default_currency='BRL', default='2')
    afternoon = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,
                              default_currency='BRL', default='3')
    weekend = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,
                            default_currency='BRL', default='2.5')

    def __str__(self):
        return "value table"
```

```
# views.py
class Entry_Vehicle(CreateView):
    model = Vehicle
    form_class = VehicleForm
    template_name = 'entry_vehicle.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vehicle_in_parking')


class Vehicle_Parking(ListView):
    template_name = 'vehicle_in_parking.html'
    model = Vehicle
    context_object_name = 'vehicles'


def exit(request, placa):
    vehicle = get_object_or_404(Veiculo, placa=placa)
    vehicle.delete()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

```
# forms.py
class VehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = [
            'brand',
            'model',
            'color',
            'vehicle_plate',
        ]
```

I think need to create a template for registering vehicles that have left parking lot, but I don't know how to get access to deleted objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's a model problem. The vehicle its just the vehicle, what you want to record is the parking. A vehicle enter and one point leave, this is the parking. A vehicle can have multiple parkings during its lifetime.

Vehicle 1 ---- N Parking

Comment: So, do I need to create a Parking model that has a Many-to-one relationship with the Vehicle model?

Comment: One thing is the parking spot, another thing is to be parked. What you should record is the parking time spot as action of one vehicle.  Vehicle 1 ---- N Parking 1 --- 1 ParkingSpot

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the vehicle when it leaves. Instead, add a flag that you can filter on: `has_exited = models.BooleanField(default=False)`.

Then, in your view just filter like so:

```
def parked_vehicle_view(request):
    parked_vehicles = Vehicle.objects.filter(has_exited=False)
    render(request, 'parked_vehicles.html', {'parked_vehicles': parked_vehicles})

def exited_vehicle_view(request):
    exited_vehicles = Vehicle.objects.filter(has_exited=False)
    render(request, 'parked_vehicles.html', {'exited_vehicles': exited_vehicles})
```

Comment: How should the template handle the output of the vehicle with this flag? Because I can only do the exit after deleting

Comment: Not sure I follow. Clarified my answer a bit to add an example of views. Does that help?

Comment: Not really, because there is a form for the moment the vehicle enters the parking lot. There is no way to insert the form 'has_exited'

Comment: You had indicated that you're already deleting Vehicle instances when they leave the parking garage. I'm suggesting that rather than delete them, simply update the `has_exited` flag to True. Otherwise, you could create a second model for the exited vehicles, but you're still going to need to track them. There's no way to get access to a deleted model instance. Once it's deleted. It's gone.